# How to resize shape relative to a certain side/corner in Sketch?

Tags: shapes, resize, sketch-app

Just started using Sketch. In Illustrator, when you want to resize a shape relative to a corner or side, you simply click the desired node in the transform tool bar square, is there something similar in Sketch?

Comment: Here are the instructions: http://www.sketchapp.com/support/documentation/03-layer-basics/4-resizing-layers.html

Comment: oh wow what a random way to do it, which they just copied illustrator in this case. Thanks!